# Get a list of all available languages in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, locale

I need all available languages (with variants, like "English (United Kingdom)" )  in a DropdownButton, i couldn't find in the flutter SDK or dart builtins, so i ended scraping [this site](http://www.lingoes.net/en/translator/langcode.htm), and creating a file`lang_list.dart` with the following content

```dart
const LANGLIST = ["Afrikaans","Afrikaans (South Africa)","Arabic","Arabic (U.A.E.)","Arabic (Bahrain)","Arabic (Algeria)","Arabic (Egypt)","Arabic (Iraq)","Arabic (Jordan)","Arabic (Kuwait)","Arabic (Lebanon)","Arabic (Libya)","Arabic (Morocco)","Arabic (Oman)","Arabic (Qatar)","Arabic (Saudi Arabia)","Arabic (Syria)","Arabic (Tunisia)","Arabic (Yemen)","Azeri (Latin)","Azeri (Latin) (Azerbaijan)","Azeri (Cyrillic) (Azerbaijan)","Belarusian","Belarusian (Belarus)","Bulgarian","Bulgarian (Bulgaria)","Bosnian (Bosnia and Herzegovina)","Catalan","Catalan (Spain)","Czech","Czech (Czech Republic)","Welsh","Welsh (United Kingdom)","Danish","Danish (Denmark)","German","German (Austria)","German (Switzerland)","German (Germany)","German (Liechtenstein)","German (Luxembourg)","Divehi","Divehi (Maldives)","Greek","Greek (Greece)","English","English (Australia)","English (Belize)","English (Canada)","English (Caribbean)","English (United Kingdom)","English (Ireland)","English (Jamaica)","English (New Zealand)","English (Republic of the Philippines)","English (Trinidad and Tobago)","English (United States)","English (South Africa)","English (Zimbabwe)","Esperanto","Spanish","Spanish (Argentina)","Spanish (Bolivia)","Spanish (Chile)","Spanish (Colombia)","Spanish (Costa Rica)","Spanish (Dominican Republic)","Spanish (Ecuador)","Spanish (Castilian)","Spanish (Spain)","Spanish (Guatemala)","Spanish (Honduras)","Spanish (Mexico)","Spanish (Nicaragua)","Spanish (Panama)","Spanish (Peru)","Spanish (Puerto Rico)","Spanish (Paraguay)","Spanish (El Salvador)","Spanish (Uruguay)","Spanish (Venezuela)","Estonian","Estonian (Estonia)","Basque","Basque (Spain)","Farsi","Farsi (Iran)","Finnish","Finnish (Finland)","Faroese","Faroese (Faroe Islands)","French","French (Belgium)","French (Canada)","French (Switzerland)","French (France)","French (Luxembourg)","French (Principality of Monaco)","Galician","Galician (Spain)","Gujarati","Gujarati (India)","Hebrew","Hebrew (Israel)","Hindi","Hindi (India)","Croatian","Croatian (Bosnia and Herzegovina)","Croatian (Croatia)","Hungarian","Hungarian (Hungary)","Armenian","Armenian (Armenia)","Indonesian","Indonesian (Indonesia)","Icelandic","Icelandic (Iceland)","Italian","Italian (Switzerland)","Italian (Italy)","Japanese","Japanese (Japan)","Georgian","Georgian (Georgia)","Kazakh","Kazakh (Kazakhstan)","Kannada","Kannada (India)","Korean","Korean (Korea)","Konkani","Konkani (India)","Kyrgyz","Kyrgyz (Kyrgyzstan)","Lithuanian","Lithuanian (Lithuania)","Latvian","Latvian (Latvia)","Maori","Maori (New Zealand)","FYRO Macedonian","FYRO Macedonian (Former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia)","Mongolian","Mongolian (Mongolia)","Marathi","Marathi (India)","Malay","Malay (Brunei Darussalam)","Malay (Malaysia)","Maltese","Maltese (Malta)","Norwegian (Bokm?l)","Norwegian (Bokm?l) (Norway)","Dutch","Dutch (Belgium)","Dutch (Netherlands)","Norwegian (Nynorsk) (Norway)","Northern Sotho","Northern Sotho (South Africa)","Punjabi","Punjabi (India)","Polish","Polish (Poland)","Pashto","Pashto (Afghanistan)","Portuguese","Portuguese (Brazil)","Portuguese (Portugal)","Quechua","Quechua (Bolivia)","Quechua (Ecuador)","Quechua (Peru)","Romanian","Romanian (Romania)","Russian","Russian (Russia)","Sanskrit","Sanskrit (India)","Sami (Northern)","Sami (Northern) (Finland)","Sami (Skolt) (Finland)","Sami (Inari) (Finland)","Sami (Northern) (Norway)","Sami (Lule) (Norway)","Sami (Southern) (Norway)","Sami (Northern) (Sweden)","Sami (Lule) (Sweden)","Sami (Southern) (Sweden)","Slovak","Slovak (Slovakia)","Slovenian","Slovenian (Slovenia)","Albanian","Albanian (Albania)","Serbian (Latin) (Bosnia and Herzegovina)","Serbian (Cyrillic) (Bosnia and Herzegovina)","Serbian (Latin) (Serbia and Montenegro)","Serbian (Cyrillic) (Serbia and Montenegro)","Swedish","Swedish (Finland)","Swedish (Sweden)","Swahili","Swahili (Kenya)","Syriac","Syriac (Syria)","Tamil","Tamil (India)","Telugu","Telugu (India)","Thai","Thai (Thailand)","Tagalog","Tagalog (Philippines)","Tswana","Tswana (South Africa)","Turkish","Turkish (Turkey)","Tatar","Tatar (Russia)","Tsonga","Ukrainian","Ukrainian (Ukraine)","Urdu","Urdu (Islamic Republic of Pakistan)","Uzbek (Latin)","Uzbek (Latin) (Uzbekistan)","Uzbek (Cyrillic) (Uzbekistan)","Vietnamese","Vietnamese (Viet Nam)","Xhosa","Xhosa (South Africa)","Chinese","Chinese (S)","Chinese (Hong Kong)","Chinese (Macau)","Chinese (Singapore)","Chinese (T)","Zulu","Zulu (South Africa)"];
```

so i can import in other files and uses this list.

Is this implementation ok? is there a method from flutter that does the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "language_pickers" Package.

https://pub.dev/packages/language_pickers

Answer (score 10):

You can retrieve all supportedLocales that you already defined in `MateralApp` .

```
context.findAncestorWidgetOfExactType<MaterialApp>()?.supportedLocales
```

Comment: `context.findAncestorWidgetOfExactType<WidgetsApp>()?.supportedLocales`

Answer (score 2):

Flutter and Dart don't have this built in. If this solution works for you, I don't see an issue with it.

Answer (score 0):

Also one more think which i faced is languages which is not mention in this class (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_localizations/GlobalMaterialLocalizations-class.html)

is also work for me (like i use Sanskrit Language) and this language not mentioned in this class

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).